# SMTP Mail not sending - Codeigniter Email Library

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-3

I'm having issues in sending mail through SMTP Protocol.

**Welcome.php**

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config = array();
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.zoho.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'support@domain.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '**************';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config["smtp_crypto"] = "ssl";

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('support@domain.com', 'Support name'); // change it to yours
$this->email->to($to);// change it to yours
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);

    if($this->email->send())
    {
      echo "Success! - An email has been sent to ".$to;
    }
    else
    { 
      show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
      return false;
    }
}
```

**Here is the output error:**

```
An Error Was Encountered
220 mx.zohomail.com SMTP Server ready June 29, 2018 5:16:40 AM PDT 

hello: 

The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
Date: Fri, 29 Jun 2018 12:16:40 +0000
From: "Support Name" <support@domain.com>
Return-Path: <support@domain.com>
To: recipent@gmail.com
Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?=43=6F=70=79=20=61=6C=6C=20=74=68=65?=
Reply-To: <support@domain.com>
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
X-Sender: support@domain.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5b36232840595@domain.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5b3623284061c"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_5b3623284061c
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Some


--B_ALT_5b3623284061c
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Some Email Description=0A=0A Some Email Description

--B_ALT_5b3623284061c--
```

> Note: The script is working fine on localhost, as well as multiple
>   other hostings but not working on VPS Hosting.

These are the things to remember:

1. The code is fine (Tried in different hosting and it works)
2. Changing `$config['protocol'] = "smtp";` to `$config['protocol'] = "sendmail";` it works. But i want to send mail only through SMTP Protocol.
3. Using Zoho Mail SMTP Protocols (smtp.zoho.com)
4. Tried, Google SMTP, Still not sending. (Used PHPMailer Library to test with the credentials. It's working on them.)

Comment: But, with the same credentials, tried with the PHPMailer in same VPS. It works there. Mail is sending as expected. The problem is only on CodeIgniter. So weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**
The problem was **fixed**! The culprit was **Valid Hostname** & **Reverse DNS**.

**Detailed info:**
Due to misconfiguration, SMTP was responding around `7 - 10 secs`. According to [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html), if we don't specify the `smtp_timeout`, it will take default which is `5 sec`. 
So I changed the `smtp_timeout` from default `5 sec` to `10 sec` and **it works**.

After figuring out what was the problem, found that the SMTP responding slow. There was no **valid hostname, Reverse DNS** added. So added that. Now it's working as expected. Now I removed the `smtp_timeout` field. It's working now.

Comment: its weird, but it works, it saves me.. omg thank u

Answer (score 2):

I Hobe this code work fine

```
$Config = [
  'protocol'  => 'smtp', 
  'smtp_host' => 'smtp.zoho.com', 
  'smtp_port' =>  465, 
  'smtp_user' => 'support@domain.com', 
  'smtp_pass' => '**************', 
  'mailtype'  => 'html', 
  'charset'   => 'utf-8'
];
$this->load->library('email',$config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('support@domain.com', 'Support name'); // change it to yours
$this->email->to($to);// change it to yours
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
if($this->email->send()){
   echo "Success! - An email has been sent to ".$to;
}
else{ 
   show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
   return false;
}
```

Comment: is your configuration correct? maybe your SMTP server isn't correct

Comment: Tried with the PHPMailer. It worked. And the script is working on other hostings as well... I'm 100% sure that the credentials is correct.

Comment: Yea.. Even the code is working on some hosting. but on the VPS, its not working.. Is there any requirement of sending mail in codeigniter? Should check out those.

Answer (score 1):

Sending emails through SMTP can be very tricky due to nowadays security checks.

Verify if:

1. you **have the rDNS** on your server and it's matching your server IP
2. **disable the 2-step auth** on the email you are using to send emails from
3. **have IMAP and POP enabled** on the email you are using to send emails from

Change the CI settings as follows:

```
    //Settings for CI
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';  
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.zoho.com'; 
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'anyemail@server.com'; 
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '***********';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';

    //Google Settings for CI
    $config['protocol'] = 'ssmtp';  
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://ssmtp.gmail.com'; 
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'anyemail@server.com'; 
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '***********';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';

    //general settings
    $config['_smtp_auth'] = TRUE; //important
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = 30;
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    //optional
    $config['wrapchars'] = 76;
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
```